# Making my columns mobile responsive for all phone screens?

Tags: html, css, mobile, flexbox, grid

I recently made a change to my container and columns in my skills sections. When I view the website on my I-phone XR the container and columns are squished. it wasn't orignally like this but i did make a change and now if it viewed on anything with a width: higher than 375px it is just squished and not stacked on top of each other.[How it looks on my phone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fADsh.png)
[This is how I wanted to look at higher mobile Widths.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPXx1.png)

```
 #skills {
        
      
      justify-content: space-around;
      height: 30vh;
       min-height: 70vh;
       
       background: #090a0f; 
       
    }

    #skills h2{
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        padding-top: 30px;
        color: #090a0f;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #skills h6 {
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        color: #6666ff;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #skills p {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu';
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    #skills .content-wrap .container {
        max-width: 1200px;
        /* height: 0vh !important; */
        min-height: 80vh;
        text-align: center;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 20px;
        height: 75vh;
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px rgba(57,56, 61, 0.205);
        display: flex;
        /* -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        flex-grow: 1; */
        
    }

    #skills .container .column {
       
        display: block;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        flex-basis: 33%;
        border-bottom: 0px solid #e2e2e2;
        border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
        /* margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px; */
    }

    #skills .container .column:last-child {
        border-right: none;
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    #skills .container .column #skills-icon{
        margin: 20px 20px;
        font-size: 35px;
        color: #6666ff;

  
    }

    #skills .container .card p {
        font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the @media screen css rule is exactly for this matter , and it really simple to use:
just define how your html elements should act in relation to the screen size that the device has .

for more explanation : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: I've tried media queries but that isn't solving this specific problem whenIi set up the original media query everything worked find I made some changes with the length of the skills container and thats when it started to mess up.